# MySQL - trying to select a range from the first day of previous month at midnight, to the first day of the current month at midnight

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working with MySQL, and attempting a specific time range query. For example if it's august now, I'm attempting to query from September 1st at midnight, to August 1st at midnight.

So far I'm able to get my date range successfully selected thanks to a prior question, but the problems I'm having are:
-My database columns for time are in UTC, and I need to convert to my timezone
-I'm having trouble adding the specific time into my query.

Here is my current query:

```
select column1,date_time_column from table.x
where date_time_column > concat(last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month), '%Y-%m-%d 05:00:00') + interval 1 day
and date_time_column < concat(last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month), '%Y-%m-%d 05:00:00') + interval 1 day
order by date_time_column
;
```

I'm attempting to put my specific time as 05:00:00, which is midnight in my DB, but right now when I run my select, it's still showing 00:00:00 times, which makes me think my time isn't applying or I have my syntax for adding the time incorrect. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: With current month is August, `last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month)` gives you `2021-06-30` .. June but you're trying to query from Sept 1st to Aug 1st.

Comment: _".. when I run my select, it's still showing 00:00:00 .."_ your `SELECT` consists of `column1, date_time_column`. So what you're saying is that if let's say you have a date like '2021-08-01 00:00:00' in the table, it wasn't suppose to show in the result but it's showing even you already filter `date_time_column > '2021-08-01 05:00:00'`, correct?

Comment: I'm doing - interval 2 months, but selecting last_day to get last day of June, then adding an interval of one day to get Sept 1st.

Comment: Wait, that doesn't make sense. Last day of june + interval 1 day doesn't get you Sept 1st.. it will return you July 1st..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATE_FORMAT` instead of `CONCAT`

> ```
> SELECT
> DATE_FORMAT(last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month), '%Y-%m-%d 05:00:00') + interval 1 day,
> DATE_FORMAT(last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month), '%Y-%m-%d 05:00:00') + interval 1 day
> ```
>
> ```
> DATE_FORMAT(last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month), '%Y-%m-%d 05:00:00') + interval 1 day | DATE_FORMAT(last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month), '%Y-%m-%d 05:00:00') + interval 1 day
> :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 2021-07-01 05:00:00                                                                       | 2021-08-01 05:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8096f421e80096479580019996255d70)*

```
select column1,date_time_column from table.x
where date_time_column > DATE_FORMAT(last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month), '%Y-%m-%d 05:00:00') + interval 1 day
and date_time_column < DATE_FORMAT(last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month), '%Y-%m-%d 05:00:00') + interval 1 day
order by date_time_column
;
```

Comment: Awesome, this absolutely worked like a charm. Thank you so much! Once I get 15 reputation I'll make sure to upvote the answer!